# Splitting string with html line break as separator

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I'm currently exploring the Python wikipedia library, to scrape corporations information from Wikipedia pages. I am having challenges trying to split the texts in a html table cell `<td>` separated by `<br>` into a list of names, so that I can clean up the site references and positions attached to the name of key people within a corporation.

Here is my code:

```
import wikipedia as wiki
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = wiki.page("Maxis Communications")
bs4page = bs(page.html())
vcard = bs4page.find_all("table", class_='infobox vcard')

industry_th = vcard[0].find('th', text='Industry')
industry_tr = industry_th.parent
industry_td = industry_tr.find('td', class_='infobox-data category')

founder_td = vcard[0].find('td', class_='infobox-data agent')
founders = founder_td.getText()
founder = founders.split("<br>")
founder_tr = founder_td.parent
founder_th = founder_tr.find('th').getText()

website_th = vcard[0].find('th', text="Website")
website_tr = website_th.parent
website = website_tr.find('a').attrs['href']
print(f"Maxis is in the {industry_td.getText()} industry, and the {founder_th.lower()} is/are {founder[0]}. The website for the business is {website}.")
```

The result that I get is:

`Maxis is in the Telecommunications industry, and the key people is/are Mokhzani Mahathir,[1] ChairmanGökhan Ogut CEO. The website for the business is https://www.maxis.com.my.`

Appreciate it if anyone could share how to get the names splitted by html line breaks `<br>`. Thank you in advance!

*Edit:
I found an answer to this, thank you @t4kq for the tips. Here is how I will write the code:*

```
page = wiki.page("Maxis Communications")
bs4page = bs(page.html())
vcard = bs4page.find_all("table", class_='infobox vcard')

industry_th = vcard[0].find('th', text='Industry')
industry_tr = industry_th.parent
industry_td = industry_tr.find('td', class_='infobox-data category')

founder_td = vcard[0].find('td', class_='infobox-data agent')
founders = []
for element in founder_td.stripped_strings:
    if  element[0] != "[":
        founders.append(element)
for i, founder in enumerate(founders):
    if founder == ",":
        founders[i-1] = ", ".join((founders[i-1], founders[i+1]))
        del founders[i:i+2]
f = ', '.join([str(elem) for elem in founders])

founder_tr = founder_td.parent
founder_th = founder_tr.find('th').getText()

website_th = vcard[0].find('th', text="Website")
website_tr = website_th.parent
website = website_tr.find('a').attrs['href']
print(f"Maxis is in the {industry_td.getText()} industry, and the {founder_th.lower()} is/are {f}. The website for the business is {website}.")
```

Comment: It looks like you HAVE fetched the names, and you HAVE split them on `<br>`.  So, what is not working?

Comment: @TimRoberts I used `{founder[0]}` in my print line, that should return the first name from the list, before the line break, i.e. `Mokhzani Mahathir, [1] Charman`, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what are you looking for?

```
import wikipedia as wiki
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = wiki.page("Maxis Communications")
bs4page = bs(page.html(), "html.parser")

vcard = bs4page.find_all("table", class_='infobox vcard')

industry_th = vcard[0].find('th', text='Industry')
industry_tr = industry_th.parent
industry_td = industry_tr.find('td', class_='infobox-data category')

founder_td = vcard[0].find('td', class_='infobox-data agent')

split_founder_elements = founder_td.prettify().split('\n')
founder = []
for element in split_founder_elements:
    stripped_element = element.strip()
    if stripped_element[0] not in ['[', '<'] and len(stripped_element) > 1:
        founder.append(stripped_element)

founder_tr = founder_td.parent
founder_th = founder_tr.find('th').getText()

website_th = vcard[0].find('th', text="Website")
website_tr = website_th.parent
website = website_tr.find('a').attrs['href']
print(f"Maxis is in the {industry_td.getText()} industry, and the {founder_th.lower()} is/are {founder[0]}. The website for the business is {website}.")
```

```
Maxis is in the Telecommunications industry, and the key people is/are Mokhzani Mahathir. The website for the business is https://www.maxis.com.my.
```

`founder` list is like

```
['Mokhzani Mahathir', 'Chairman', 'Gökhan Ogut CEO']
```

Comment: That's very close, thank you. I was hoping to get names only though.

Comment: I have found an answer, please see my edit above.